# next js middleware error on getting the query from the url

Tags: next.js, middleware

im trying to take the token from the url of a route in my site but the middleware log 3 times the token and in the second time the token is null
while i logged the req url my url that im in is http://localhost:3000/auth/newPassword
but in the second render its http://localhost:3000/_next/static/chunks/pages/auth/newPassword.js?ts=1667894719054
someone knows what is the problem here?

i sent an email for new password to the user email with query token in the url
i wan the middleware to check if the token is valid before accessing the new password route
and then verify it there but its render null for me in the second time and that crashed my project

```
import { NextResponse, NextRequest } from "next/server";
import { verify } from "jsonwebtoken";

const secret = process.env.JWT_SECRET!;

export default async function middleware(req: NextRequest) {
  const url = req.url;
  const token = await req.nextUrl.searchParams.get("token")!;
  const cookies = req.cookies;
  if (url.includes("/auth/newPassword")) {
    console.log(url);

    if (token === undefined) {
      return NextResponse.redirect("http://localhost:3000/auth/signin");
    }
    try {
      verify(token, secret);
      return NextResponse.next();
    } catch (e) {
      return NextResponse.redirect("http://localhost:3000/auth/signin");
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That because when you load `http://localhost:3000/auth/newPassword` next will make a request to `http://localhost:3000/_next/static/chunks/pages/auth/newPassword.js?ts=1667894719054` (i guess for hydration), this file basically contains only react related javascript stuff, and you wont that your middleware will match this route, while currently it is (because it contains `auth/newPassword`).

I sueggest to use middleware with  negative matchers :

```
export const config = {
  matcher: [
    /*
     * Match all paths except for:
     * 1. /api routes
     * 2. /_next (Next.js internals)
     * 3. /fonts (inside /public)
     * 4. /examples (inside /public)
     * 5. all root files inside /public (e.g. /favicon.ico)
     */
    '/((?!api|_next|fonts|500|examples|[\\w-]+\\.\\w+).*)',
  ],
};

export default function middleware(req: NextRequest) {
  const url = req.url;
  const token = await req.nextUrl.searchParams.get("token")!;
  const cookies = req.cookies;
  if (url.includes("/auth/newPassword")) {
    console.log(url);

    if (token === undefined) {
      return NextResponse.redirect("http://localhost:3000/auth/signin");
    }
    try {
      verify(token, secret);
      return NextResponse.next();
    } catch (e) {
      return NextResponse.redirect("http://localhost:3000/auth/signin");
    }
   }
}
```

Comment: thanks man that helped me get the url i need but i saw now that the jose not working to me while verify the token i got this error - (middleware)\node_modules\jose\dist\browser\lib\check_key_type.js (7:0) @ symmetricTypeCheck     
error - unhandledRejection: Key for the HS256 algorithm must be one of type CryptoKey or Uint8Array. and i got null from the verify

Comment: can i use jsonwebtken to set the token and verify it with jose? or its not working like that cause that what im doing..

Comment: @EilonShamir honestly  i've no idead how jose works, but it seems is not related to the original question